# How to change the contain a column to another column in php?

Tags: php, html

I wanna ask about how to change the contain of the table in a column to another column.

I have the following code below :

```html
<h4 align="center">--- PRESISI ----</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Tema</th>
      <th>Presisi</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
                $no =0;
    $hasil=array(1,2,3);    
                foreach ($data_view as $data) { 
                $no++;
                 ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo "$no."; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $data->nama; ?>
      </td>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php for($i=0;$i<count($hasil);$i++){?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php
       echo $hasil[$i];//echo $presisi[1]; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> The table shows us with consists :
>
> No | Tema | Presisi
>
> 1. | Sistem Informasi Akuntansi |
> 2. | Badan Usaha |
> 3. | Konflik Sosial |
> 4. | Kemerdekaan Indonesia |
> 5. | Ekosistem Alam |
> 6. | Kerajaan Kuno Indonesia |
>
>    1
>
>    2
>
>    3

But i want to change the contain the table with consist like that :

> The table should be consists :
>
> No | Tema | Presisi
>
> 1. | Sistem Informasi Akuntansi | 1
> 2. | Badan Usaha | 2
> 3. | Konflik Sosial | 3
> 4. | Kemerdekaan Indonesia |
> 5. | Ekosistem Alam |
> 6. | Kerajaan Kuno Indonesia |

for more clearly, you can see the table what should i change like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRh4k.jpg)

Comment: I created a snippet. Just formatting the snippet, it shows you are generating invalid HTML: `<?php } ?>
      <?php for($i=0;$i<count($hasil);$i++){?>` should at least have a </tr> before it

Answer (score -1):

try this loop through the `$hasil` using `$no` value

```
<tbody>
            <?php 
            $no =0;
            $hasil=array(1,2,3);                
            foreach ($data_view as $data) { 
            $no++;
             ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo "$no."; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data->nama; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo (isset($hasil[$no - 1])) ? $hasil[$no - 1] : ""?></td>
      </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add just one `TR` with 3 `TD` inside and you don't need second loop, just check if array has got element for index $no :

```
 <tr>
              <td><?php echo "$no."; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $data->nama; ?></td>           
              <td><?php if isset($hasil[$no-1]) { echo $hasil[$no-1]; } ?> </td>                      
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct answer. I am so sorry, i did not mean that, because i am still amateur using stackoverflow, and i accidentally hit the downvote button ..i hope you refer.  sir... thanks...